# Testing a iOS application that uses a web server on the simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, http, tcp, simulator

I have an iOS application that has a HTTP server in order to communicate between devices, and am trying to test it via the simulator. However, when I run it on the simulator it seems that the server portion doesn't work, even when I try to connect to the server from the same app using localhost.

On the device my code works fine so I know it's not a problem there, so it may be a limitation of the simulator. However if I can find a way to get this to work on there it will be much easier to test certain things.

If someone has any ideas let me know.

Comment: Is your Mac connected to the Internet ?

Comment: Yes, my mac is connected to the net, though it shouldn't matter since I am using localhost.

Comment: simulator sends a different User-Agent header... just in case you are using it to identify the client.

Comment: User-Agent doesn't seem to be the problem, I just cannot connect.

Comment: do you get en Exception/Error while connecting or what?

Comment: might sound trivial, but the simulator sometimes has connection issues that are solved by simply closing and restarting it... (i guess in that case you already solved your problem anyway :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a few things and eventually I got it to work. First, I upgraded XCode and iOS to the latest version. Then when I ran it again I realized that I already had a server on that port, so after changing the port number in a few places I got it working.

Answer (score 2):

Can you test the web server separate from the application?

I use a program to test called SOAPUI http://www.soapui.org/.

Maybe the problem isn't the App but the web server!

Comment: The web server I am using I based on this code: https://gist.github.com/enigmaticape/4024992. However since I have tested this code on several devices and it works without issue, it seems that the issue is with the simulator not supporting creating a server, as opposed to the code itself.

Comment: I have two tests you can do. One is create a new project on xcode and add on it only the web server call. Than we can see if the problem isn't another code on the original project. The other one is test the call on a Device not on IOS Simulator, do you have a developer account?

Comment: Regarding your first suggestion, my project doesn't actually do anything until it gets requests in, so I am basically just testing the web server. For your second suggestion, as I mentioned I have already tested on several live devices using a dev account.

Answer (score 2):

> However, when I run it on the simulator it seems that the server portion doesn't work, even when I try to connect to the server from the same app using localhost.

Have you tried *man in the middle* communication traffic monitoring? Responds server correctly?